# Reading boost serialization files from C++ into R

Tags: c++, r, serialization, boost

First of all, I'm not a programmer, I'm a biologist that tries to use C++ :). So, I'm not really experienced with C++.

I have a program that, in a simplified way, simulates evolution of populations. My population is a class that consists of objects of other classes (like genotype, phenotype, fitness - these are vector of vectors). I'm looking for a way to output the content of the population class during the simulation. This output should be possible to be read again by the simulation program, but it should be also possible to read it in a scripting language like R to run statistical analyses. I've tried my luck with boost serialization (text_oarchive, text_iarchive) and it works fine for writing and reading. But, I couldn't find a way to read these files into R (maybe I'm overseeing something?).

My question now, is there a way to do this with boost serialization? Or are there some better and easier ways to solve such a problem?

**Long story short: I'm looking for a way to output the content of a class object to read it again into C++, but also read it into R to do some analyses.**

Comment: I don't think Boost's serialization format is usable outside Boost. You could use some other format, like CSV (for table-shaped data) or JSON (for tree-shaped data).

Comment: C++ is pretty expert friendly. Not that I'm trying to discourage you. But is there no other choice but C++?

Comment: depending on what exactly you want to write to the file using boost serialization might be overkill. Writing/reading a table of numbers to/from a file is a quite beginner friendly task. I would even start with text files so you can always check that the data is written correctly

Comment: converting the object to JSON would be a better option. There are tons of C++ JSON [de]serialization libraries and that will make the data much easier to work with in any language.